# Imageio flips black and white

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imageio

I have a binary black and white image as a `.tif` file. I do this

```
image = imageio.imread(path)
print ' Min and max ', image.min(), image.max(), image.shape, type(image[0,0])
imageio.imsave(path, image)
```

Which prints

```
Min and max  0 255 (1024, 1024) <type 'numpy.uint8'>
```

However, after I run that, black and white colors have reversed. What is going on?

When I try this command

```
identify -verbose 6hr-001-DIC.tif
```

on the pre-processed image, I see

```
tiff:photometric: min-is-white
```

But after I run the python code, it shows
tiff:photometric: min-is-black

So how can I address this, i.e. make sure it's not getting changed?

Comment: What is the format of the image?

Comment: .tif files, please see edit above

Comment: TIF supports *"min is black"* or *"min is white"* in its *Photometric Interpretation* tag. It may be that Python `imageio` does not respect that. Try using `tiffump` on your input and output files, or **ImageMagick** `identify -verbose image.tif` to check.

Comment: You can also set the tag yourself with `tiffset -s 262 0|1 image.tif`

Comment: In my longer comment above, read *"respect"* as *"respect or preserve"*.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good catch. I updated my original question. How can I make sure imageio respects this?

Comment: Not sure. At least we know the problem. It seems you can set it on writing (see `photometric` here https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_tiff.html#tiff I am not sure how you get the current setting on read though in order to preserve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mark Stechell pointed you need to use the `photometric` metadata field. First make sure you have installed [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/). For the sake of demonstration I am using the [marbles](http://netghost.narod.ru/gff/sample/images/tiff/gmarbles.tif) image in grayscale. Now the code:

```
import imageio

image = imageio.imread('gmarbles.tif')
print(' Min and max ', image.min(), image.max(), image.shape, type(image[0, 0]))

image.meta['photometric'] = 'miniswhite'
imageio.imsave('white.tif', image)
```

[image: white image]

or alternative set to `'minisblack'`:

[image: black image]